# How can I append each output of subprocess into a list?

Tags: python, list, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to take the output of p5, they are mac address, and I want to store them into a list.

I know that mac addresses are printed in byte type but I can't manage to get them in the type I want.

```
p3 = subprocess.Popen(["iw", "dev", displayInt, "station", "dump"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

p4 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "Station"], stdin=p3.stdout,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

p5 = subprocess.Popen(["cut", "-f", "2", "-s", "-d", " "], stdin=p4.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in iter(p5.stdout.readline,''):
    maclist.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
print(maclist)
```

I would like to have an output like:

```
[a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6 , a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6]
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `readline()` instead of `readline`?

Comment: @razdi, no, not with the arcane form of `iter`

Comment: Which line is actually raising the error?

Comment: `iter(p5.stdout.readline,'')` -> `iter(p5.stdout.readline, b'')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using Python 3. In Python 3, `stdout` is a stream of bytes. If you want to convert that into string, add the `encoding='utf8'` paramter to the `Popen()` call, for example:

```
p5 = subprocess.Popen(
    ["cut", "-f", "2", "-s", "-d", " "],
    encoding="utf8",
    stdin=p4.stdout,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You might have to include the `encoding` parameter for other calls. Also, instead of:

```
for line in iter(p5.stdout.readline,''):
```

You might want to try this, which is shorter and easier to understand:

```
for line in p5.stdout:
```